# @Transactional is not starting a transaction in standalone application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, spring-java-config

I have created following example . But I am not getting the expected result.
Here is my code :

**1.application.properties**

```
################### JDBC Configuration ##########################
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/hsqldb;shutdown=true
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=


################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

**2. DatabaseConfig.java**

```java
/**
 * 
 * load Hibernate Session factory to get session ,load Hibernate Transaction
 * Manager to deal with transaction
 * 
 */

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClass;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String showSQL;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddl;

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {

        Properties hp = new Properties();
        hp.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        hp.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSQL);
        hp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        hp.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        return hp;

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource driverManagerDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(driverManagerDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.orbit.hibernate.entities" });

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager tm = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return tm;

    }

}
```

**3. AppConfig.java**

```java
/**
 * 
 * This class has all the beans required at application level
 * 
 */
@Configuration
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
@ComponentScan("com.orbit")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer pphc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        pphc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        pphc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return pphc;
    }
}
```

**4.User.java**

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**5. UserRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save() {
        User u = new User();
        String random = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        u.setName("mks" + random);
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(u);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("FROM User");
        List<User> users = q.getResultList();
        return users;
    }
}
```

**6. UserService.java**

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return userRepo.getAll();
    }

    public void save() {
        userRepo.save();
    }
}
```

**7. AppLaunch.java**

```java
public class LaunchApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        UserService userService = ctx.getBean(UserService.class);
        userService.save();
        userService.save();
        System.out.println("Printing all user");
        List<User> user = userService.getAllUser();
        user.forEach(System.out::println);
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

when I run AppLaunch.java class . following execption occurs :

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: persist is not valid without active transaction

here is my pom.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.orbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring.hibernate.java.config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring.hibernate.java.config</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What I am not doing right, here ?

Here is complete stack trace :

> Apr 12, 2017 8:16:35 PM
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@fa5d3:
>   startup date [Wed Apr 12 20:16:35 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   Apr 12, 2017 8:16:36 PM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
>   setDriverClassName INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver Apr
>   12, 2017 8:16:36 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412:
>   Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final} Apr 12, 2017 8:16:36 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found Apr 12, 2017 8:16:37 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: persist is not valid without active
>   transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.persist(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.orbit.repositories.UserRepository.save(UserRepository.java:26)    at
>   com.orbit.services.UserService.save(UserService.java:25)  at
>   com.orbit.services.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6492a26b.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
>     at
>   com.orbit.services.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$15a51388.save()
>     at com.orbit.main.LaunchApp.main(LaunchApp.java:16)

Comment: No transaction is initiated in your code maybe adding propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW to your @Transactional will solve your issue

Comment: @Nemesis: I tired that too . still same result

Comment: Try to specify the transcation manager in your annotation like this:  `@Transactional(value="transactionManager")`

Comment: I also tried this by giving @Bean("txManager") and then specifying transactionManager attribute in @Transcational

Comment: `transactionmanager` is not configured in your @configuration. You may wan to configure it for this to work. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove this property and run again.

```
hp.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
```

Comment: I am using contexctual session . hence it is required .

Comment: try using this annotation  @EnableTransactionManagement

Comment: You need to remove that property as that property destroys springs proper integration. Spring has its own contextual session implementation for hibernate.

Comment: @M.Deinum : How can I get that contextual session details

Comment: Which details? You don't need to do anything? Not sure what you are asking with that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the transaction Manager as specified in the spring transaction document https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing-tx

Also please edit save method and add beginTransaction as follows:

```
    public void save() {
        User u = new User();
        String random = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        u.setName("mks" + random);
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(u);
        trans.commit();

    }
```

Comment: is it relavent ?

Comment: You will actually get to know ins and outs of using @Transactional here

Comment: Kayv: well I know what you mentioned in the link . My question is that I am not running any test . So is that relavant there . I actually want to use spring app based transaction functionality in standalone application

Comment: It will work but question is that why the above code is not working , Am i not understanding spring transaction management correctly ,or something is missing ?